# x86/x64 instructions generated by .net jitter

Tags: .net, .net-core, jit, coreclr

When running a .net program I know how to look at the MSIL. But how do I view the x86/x64 assembly instructions generated by the .net jitter on linux/mac platforms?

Comment: Debug > Windows > Disassembly.  They are not different on Linux/Mac.

Comment: What tool is this under- Visual Studio? Sorry I'm new the ecosystem. I was hoping there's some command line switch similar to jvm.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to build CoreCLR yourself, you can follow [this guide](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/viewing-jit-dumps.md) to make CoreCLR show you the disassembly.